# Prefab.Instantiate new object

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Im having problem with prefab.I want to replace a sphere from its original position after it's thrown into the air.So I read and I followed steps on how to create a prefab.
Currenty, I have a sphere, a script, and a prefab.Script is already attached to the sphere and the sphere was dragged into a prefab.

And how  I can instantiate the new sphere with this code below.

```
    function Update(){

if (Input.touchCount == 1) {

    transform.eulerAngles.x = -45;
    rigidbody.velocity=transform.forward * force;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a reference to the prefab in your script. That means a public GameObject filled via drag and drop in Unity.

```
public GameObject spherePrefab;

function Update(){
    if (spherePrefab != null) {
        GameObject go = (GameObject)Instantiate (spherePrefab);
        go.transform.eulerAngles = -45;
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: I'm having problem with your codes:
I modified my previous codes and able to create this.`function Update() {
if (Input.touchCount == 1) {
      transform.eulerAngles.x = -20; 
      rigidbody.velocity=transform.forward * 50;  
    
var respawns = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Respawn");
 
for (var respawn in respawns)
    Instantiate (spherePrefab, respawn.transform.position, respawn.transform.rotation);

    }
    
    }`.
My problem is I want only to create one sphere at a time and generate another if once is thrown.please help.

Comment: So you jsut need the right time to respawn once. Don't put it in Update but at the place where you start throwing.

Comment: sorry for the question. except from `function update` and `function start ` where I can put my code to generate only one object at a time.